# R : Extract a Specific Number out of a String

Tags: r

I have a vector as below

```
data <- c("6X75ML","24X37.5ML (KKK)", "6X2X75ML", "168X5CL (UUU)")
```

here i want to extract the first number before the "X" for each of the elements.
In case of situations with 2 "X" i.e. "6X2X75CL" the number 12 (6 multiplied by 2) should be calculated.

expected output

```
6, 24, 12, 168
```

Thank you for the help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also use `str_extract_all`

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(data, "\\d+(?=X)"), function(x) prod(as.numeric(x)))
#[1]   6  24  12 168
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible solution using regular expressions :

```
data <- c("6X75ML","24X37.5ML (KKK)", "6X2X75ML", "168X5CL (UUU)")

# this regular expression finds any group of digits followed 
# by a upper-case 'X' in each string and returns a list of the matches
tokens <- regmatches(data,gregexpr('[[:digit:]]+(?=X)',data,perl=TRUE))

res <- sapply(tokens,function(x)prod(as.numeric(x)))
> res
[1]   6  24  12 168
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method using base R:

```
dataList <- strsplit(data, split="X")
sapply(dataList, function(x) Reduce("*", as.numeric(head(x, -1))))
[1]   6  24  12 168
```

`strplit` breaks up the vector along "X". The resulting list is fed to `sapply` which the performs an operation on all but the final element of each vector in the list. The operation is to transform the elements into numerics and the multiply them. The final element is dropped using `head(x, -1)`.

As @zheyuan-li comments, `prod` can fill in for `Reduce` and will probably be a bit faster:

```
sapply(dataList, function(x) prod(as.numeric(head(x, -1))))
[1]   6  24  12 168
```

Comment: Thanks all ..... this is amazing.... I have been going by it all wrong ....did not know you could solve it in one line.....

Answer (score 1):

```
ind=regexpr("X",data)
val=as.integer(substr(data, 1, ind-1))
data2=substring(data,ind+1)
ind2=regexpr("[0-9]+X", data2)
if (!all(ind2!=1)) {
    val2 = as.integer(substr(data2[ind2==1], 1, attr(ind2,"match.length")[ind2==1]-1))
    val[ind2==1] = val[ind2==1] * val2
}
```